# Should I be worried about a hardware error if my MacBook Pro is running ok?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, apple-hardware-test

I have recently had some trouble with my MacBook Pro 8.1 (Early 2011). After running tests, installing the old 2x2 GB RAM sticks and basically trying else everything to restore it, it turned out that the SATA cable didn't want to work with my SSD anymore, although with an older mechanical drive it was ok. So I swapped my SATA cable for a new one, installed my 2x4 GB RAM sticks again and it works again like new. Today however, out of curiousity, I ran the Apple Hardware Test again just to see if anything comes up, and I had this error:

[image]

Then I checked again using REMBER!

[image]

So which is correct?

Should I do something if there are no symptoms? Am I destroying other parts of my Mac if I just do nothing?

Answer (score 3):

- **Rember only tested less than 1 GB of your 8 GB of RAM**, as explained within the screenshot of the Rember application.

  > Memory allocated for testing: 947 MB
- Apple Hardware Test will test all of the RAM in the system, since it runs outside of macOS.

As also explained in Rember, to be able to test more RAM with the program:

> run memtest (the core of Rember) in single-user mode

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> Should I do something if there are no symptoms?

**Yes.  Absolutely.  Most definitely.**

What should you do?  Diagnose the memory.

Run the memory tests for each module in each slot *individually*.  Your goal is to determine if you hare having memory issues or memory slot issues.

You have "known working" memory (the old modules) that if you can also test with that, theoretically, should generate no errors.  Use that as your benchmark.  You will want to make notes as to what works where as you progress.

If you discover you have bad memory, replace it with new modules.  Most reputable memory manufacturers have warranties; they should replace it for you for no charge.

If it's your slot, you have two options:

- leave the slot unused
- replace the logic board

> Am I destroying other parts of my Mac if I just do nothing?

Destroying other parts?  No.  Bad memory cannot break other components.  What it can destroy is unsaved data.  Memory can cause kernel panics and even hard system freezes.  Anything unsaved at that point is lost.